anchor deploy: Account 123 has insufficient funds for spend
I am new to anchor/solana/rust and I have built and deployed an anchor program on I believe devnet, because solana config get is showing: RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com.
I've made some edits to the code, and tried to deploy the new build, and it's resulting in Account 123 has insufficient funds for spend.
When requesting another airdrop, it's resulting in Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached..
I'd like to be able to build and deploy without any restriction's. Is this possible?
Otherwise, how can I re-create a new account to request an airdrop, build and deploy? Or should I do everything in localhost?

There are multiple waits on how to get devnet sol. Ranging from airdrop to web faucet and discord bots.
Just follow the guide here:
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/solana-token-airdrop-and-faucets

Thanks, I did.
I'll try to work in localhost and deploy, the program later.
